# css topnav not on top of the page

Tags: html, css

my topnav is not on top, it has a strange padding of about 5px
for testing i just created a simple header.html + header.css
my header.html:

```
<link href="css/header.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
</div>
```

my header.css:

```
.topnav {
height: 50px;
background-color: #333;
}
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHGZR.png)

how can i get the black line to not have this white space on the top and sides (and maybe bottom)?

after some research i tired:

```
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
```

but that didnt change anything....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `padding` and `margin` of `body` tag

```
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```